# how to remove specific parts of string in python

Tags: python, text, preprocessor

I tried to remove specific words have same pattern that is specific same word next to.

`doc = ["super man good weather", "bet man nice car", "iron man awesome soup"]`

I want to remove `'super man'`, `'bet man'`, `'iron man'` . these strings have same word 'man' and I want to remove the word in front of the same word 'man' at the same time.

I tried this but, failed.

```
for string in doc:
    prep = re.sub('.* man =', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. SHould work using `re`

```
[re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}man', '', txt).strip() for txt in doc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the elegant way of doing it. But serves the purpose.

```
doc = ["super man good weather", "bet man nice car", "iron man awesome soup", "a manned mission to mars"]

keyword = " man " # to make sure that you don't remove words that contain man as substring

doc = [string.split(keyword)[1].strip() if keyword in string else string for string in doc]

print(doc)
```

*Output*

```
['good weather', 'nice car', 'awesome soup', 'a manned mission to mars']
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/RareAlarmingWearables)

***Regex based solution***

```
import re
doc = ["man super man good weather", "a bet man nice car", "iron man awesome man soup", "a manned mission to mars"]
doc = [re.sub('\w+ man ', '', string).strip() for string in doc]
print(doc)
```

*Output*

```
['man good weather', 'a nice car', 'soup', 'a manned mission to mars']
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/GullibleShyQuadrants)

Comment: if man appears more than twice times, it can't remove 'man'. but simple and useful code. thank you so much:)

Comment: @CheongRokLee I've updated the answer with regex based solution. This should work even if man appears twice in the string. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be

```
re.sub('\w+ man ', '', t)
```